# Why doesn't Array from GLib work with int in Vala?

Tags: arrays, glib, vala

This is an example of https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Array.html but instead of a string int throws C errors.

```
int main(){
   Array<int> array = new Array<int> ();
   array.append_val (3);
   array.append_val (4);

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
In file included from/usr/include/glib-2.0 / glib.h: 31.,
                 from/tmp / algorithm2.vala.JWAGYZ.c: 4:
/ tmp / algorithm2.vala.JWAGYZ.c: in the function " _vala_main»:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib / garray.h: 64:59: error: unary operation operand ' & ' must be an lvalue expression
   64 | #define g_array_append_val(a, v) g_array_append_vals (a, &(v), 1)
      / ^
/ tmp / algorithm2.vala.JWAGYZ.c: 53:2: note: in the macro extension "g_array_append_val»
   53 | g_array_append_val (array, 3);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib / garray.h: 64:59: error: unary operation operand ' & ' must be an lvalue expression
   64 | #define g_array_append_val(a, v) g_array_append_vals (a, &(v), 1)
      / ^
/ tmp / algorithm2.vala.JWAGYZ.c: 54:2: note: in the macro extension "g_array_append_val»
   54 / g_array_append_val (array, 4);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: cc exited with status 256
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying implementation of Vala generics is C pointer based. `int` is a value type rather than a reference type and does not fit well with the current implementation in Vala. One solution is to turn the `int` in to a reference type by 'boxing'. That's basically making it a nullable type: `int?`. So this works:

```
int main(){
   Array<int?> array = new Array<int?> ();
   array.append_val (3);
   array.append_val (4);

   return 0;
}
```

There is some work currently going on to get the Vala compiler to accommodate simple generics where value types are used. See [Vala merge request #52](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/merge_requests/52).

In the case of GArray, [`g_array_append_val()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html#g-array-append-val) is a macro and the documentation advises the value has to be a reference to the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the integers to an intermediate variable first. The fact that Vala doesn’t do that automatically is a Vala bug, which you should [report upstream](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/issues/new?issue%5Bassignee_id%5D=&issue%5Bmilestone_id%5D=).

Answer (score 0):

A temporary answer for the version of Vala 0.44 until you correct the error:

```
int main(){
    Array<int> array = new Array<int> ();
    int a = 3, b = 4;
    array.append_val (a);
    array.append_val (b);

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
        print ("%d\n", array.index (i));
    }

     return 0;
 }
```